# webhdfs rest api throwing file not found exception

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh, webhdfs

I am trying to open a hdfs file that is present on cdh4 cluster from cdh5 machine using webhdfs from the command line as below:

```
curl -i -L "http://namenodeIpofCDH4:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/quad/source/JSONML.java?user.name=quad&op=OPEN"
```

I am getting "File Not Found Exception" even if the file JSONML.java is present in the mentioned path in namenode as well as datanode and its trace is as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 307 TEMPORARY_REDIRECT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Mon, 22 Feb 2016 13:25:35 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Mon, 22 Feb 2016 13:25:35 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: hadoop.auth="u=quad&p=quad&t=simple&e=1456183535737&s=KdZYcA5iwJeIU2F9ZJfLSaT4qMY=";Path=/
Location: http://n3.quadratics.com:50075/webhdfs/v1/user/quad/source/JSONML.java?op=OPEN&user.name=quad&namenoderpcaddress=n1.quadratics.com:8020&offset=0
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(6.1.26.cloudera.4)

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 22 Feb 2016 13:26:28 GMT
Date: Mon, 22 Feb 2016 13:26:28 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 22 Feb 2016 13:26:28 GMT
Date: Mon, 22 Feb 2016 13:26:28 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(6.1.26.cloudera.4)

{"RemoteException":{"exception":"FileNotFoundException","javaClassName":"java.io.FileNotFoundException","message":"File does not exist: /user/quad/source/JSONML.java\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:66)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:56)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsUpdateTimes(FSNamesystem.java:1932)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsInt(FSNamesystem.java:1873)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1853)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1825)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:559)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.getBlockLocations(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:87)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:363)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1060)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2044)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2040)\n\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)\n\tat javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2038)\n"}}
```

But I don't get any error and get the status of the above file when I use the below command:

```
curl -i -L http://namenodeIpofCDH4:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/quad/source/JSONML.java?user.name=quad&op=GETFILESTATUS"
```

I get the output response as below:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Mon, 22 Feb 2016 13:38:48 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Mon, 22 Feb 2016 13:38:48 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: hadoop.auth="u=quad&p=quad&t=simple&e=1456184328134&s=sE6esO8J39O+itl+ggNzX4/WzjQ=";Path=/
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(6.1.26.cloudera.4)

{"FileStatus":{"accessTime":1456147448567,"blockSize":134217728,"group":"quad","length":14849,"modificationTime":1456143798039,"owner":"quad","pathSuffix":"","permission":"644","replication":3,"type":"FILE"}}
```

Any ideas of the reason of why opening a file is failing and fixing that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I saw a similar error when I had misconfigured my /etc/hosts
The OPEN command above returns a redirect which provides a hostname. The localhost will try and resolve this hostname based on the local DNS setup.
It will then look for the file at the IP address that the hostname resolves to. Not necessarily the one you issued the command to.