# WebHDFS FileNotFoundException rest api

Tags: hadoop, filenotfoundexception, webhdfs, httpfs

I am posting this question as a continuation of post [webhdfs rest api throwing file not found exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555252/webhdfs-rest-api-throwing-file-not-found-exception)

I have an image file I would like to OPEN through the WebHDFS rest api.

1. the file exists in hdfs and has appropriate permissions
2. I can
   `LISTSTATUS` that file and get an answer:

> curl -i "http://namenode:50070/webhdfs/v1/tmp/file.png?op=LISTSTATUS"

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 17 Jul 2020 22:47:29 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 17 Jul 2020 22:47:29 GMT
Date: Fri, 17 Jul 2020 22:47:29 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{"FileStatuses":{"FileStatus":[
{"accessTime":1594828591740,"blockSize":134217728,"childrenNum":0,"fileId":11393739,"group":"hdfs","length":104811,"modificationTime":1594828592000,"owner":"XXXX","pathSuffix":"XXXX","permission":"644","replication":3,"storagePolicy":0,"type":"FILE"}
]}}

Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 0
```

3. So the api can properly read the metadata, but I cannot get that file to OPEN:

> curl -i "http://namenode:50070/webhdfs/v1/tmp/file.png?op=OPEN"

```
HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Date: Fri, 17 Jul 2020 22:23:17 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 17 Jul 2020 22:23:17 GMT
Date: Fri, 17 Jul 2020 22:23:17 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
Location: http://datanode1:50075/webhdfs/v1/tmp/file.png?op=OPEN&namenoderpcaddress=namenode:8020&offset=0
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 0

{"RemoteException":{"exception":"FileNotFoundException","javaClassName":"java.io.FileNotFoundException","message":"Path is not a file: /tmp/file.png......
```

4. So, according to [webhdfs rest api throwing file not found exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555252/webhdfs-rest-api-throwing-file-not-found-exception), I can see that the request is passed off from the namenode to the datanode1.
   Datanode1 is in my hosts file, I can connect to it an check the status of webhdfs from there:

```
<property>
<name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
<value>true</value>
<final>true</final>
</property>
```

It is allowed, same on the namenode.

5. I also went to look at the hdfs logs on `/var/log/hadoop/hdfs/*.{log,out}` to see if I could find errors triggered when I curled, but nothing seems to happen. I see no entry pertaining to my file or webhdfs query. I tried that on the namenode and datanode1.
6. as a last ditch effort I tried to increase permissions (not ideal) from 644 (seen in point 2/) to 666

> hdfs dfs -chmod 666 /tmp/file.png

> curl -i "http://namenode:50070/webhdfs/v1/tmp/file.png?op=LISTSTATUS"

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Fri, 17 Jul 2020 23:06:18 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 17 Jul 2020 23:06:18 GMT
Date: Fri, 17 Jul 2020 23:06:18 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{"RemoteException":{"exception":"AccessControlException","javaClassName":"org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException","message":"Permission denied: user=XXXX, access=READ_EXECUTE, inode=\"/tmp/file.png\":XXXX:hdfs:drw-rw-rw-"}}
```

So it seems it did the switch but somehow I got a permission issue when relaxing the current permissions that I didnt get before? It is not like I removed the X flag, it wasn't there to begin with. Does access=READ_EXECUTE require both R and X?

Now I am at a loss as to why I can see but not read this file with HDFS. Can someone please help me troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking closer at your last error,
`... inode=\"/tmp/file.png\":XXXX:hdfs:drw-rw-rw-"}`
, it seems to indicate that `file.png` is actually a directory (leading `d` symbol) and not a file. This is consistent with the error you're getting in step #3 ***`..."message":"Path is not a file: /tmp/file.png....`**

You can double check that simply by doing `$ hdfs dfs -ls /tmp/file.png/`.

Getting back to your access error, you do need an "execute" (`x`) permission to list the files in a directory.

Comment: Indeed, I missed that. Thank you for the external point of view.
It happened when I hdfs dfs -put my image from local to hdfs the actual path is hdfs dfs -ls /tmp/file.png/file.png.
I am tunneling through ssh and have no coloring. That would have helped.
Thanks for the help!